# How can i update the product quantity in cart?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongodb-update

My cart schema

```
var CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    },
    totalQty: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    user:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    items : Array,
    orderedQty: Number
});
```

After inserting one record I have got the response

```
{
    "totalQty": 1,
    "totalPrice": 6500,
    "items": [
        {
            "qty": 1,
            "item": {
                "_id": "5b28d30888afb703508409bb",
                "name": "LENOVO VIBE K5",
                "price": 6500,
                "quantity": 15,
                "imagePath": "https://in.bmscdn.com/showcaseimage/eventimage/hereditary-17-06-2018-10-06-45-907.jpg",
                "description": "This is showcase image from bms",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "price": 6500
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5b2a3da1f4fd65265c8ab477",
    "user": "5b27898931169e074c2dc228",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to update the "qty" inside the items[] array. How can I write the update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$inc` operator:

```
db.cart.update(
    {_id: ObjectId('5b2a3da1f4fd65265c8ab477'), 'items.item._id': ObjectId('5b28d30888afb703508409bb')},
    {$inc: {"items.$.qty": value}} // Pass your increase value here
)
```

Comment: Hey @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn thanks for quick reply but i just confirm that can i access elements of items array using items.item._id?

Comment: Yes, remember to wrap the nested property inside `'nested.property'`. Find the item you want to increase and use `$inc` to increase the property of that array element

Comment: Hey @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn I have modified my update request like this                                
              Cart.update(
                    {_id: '5b2a56656d83d4194cfde63d', 'items.item._id': '5b28d30888afb703508409bb'},
                    {$inc: {"items.$.qty": 1}},(err,data)=>{
                        if(err) console.error(err);
                        res.send(data);
                    } // Pass your increase value here
                )  but in response nothing is getting updated {
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1
}

Comment: Your IDs are not `ObjectId`?

Comment: Yes they are ObjectID

Comment: I mean, if your IDs are `ObjectId` then you must wrap your id in `ObjectId('5b2a56656d83d4194cfde63d')` like I did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173477/discussion-between-sagar-pednekar-and-mnh-quyt-nguyn).

Comment: Well I tried that but I am getting "ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined"